# Where to get the JavaFX sources?

Tags: java, open-source, javafx

I've read that some months ago, Oracle agreed to make JavaFX open source. I'd like to take part in the development process but don't know where to get the development resources.

I'd appreciate some help :)

Best regards,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the development is here:

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/

Answer (score 14):

At:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/

search for 'openjfx'.

Use one of the 'master/rt' repositories, e.g.

for v2.1:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/rt/

for v2.2:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/

for v8:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/